# Entity framework code first caching

Tags: entity-framework

It is possible to use the [Entity framework caching and tracing framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32) with the new entity framework 4.1 code first?  If so then is there a good example of this, otherwise what is the best way to cache some queries?

Comment: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx) is one

Comment: Good question, I'm curious at your outcome.  I have limited caching in my MVC3 web app in which I used EF 4.1.  I implemented caching at the website layer for dropdowns and common psuedo-static lookup sets.  I use built-in ASP.NET Cache to cache collections returned from calls to my service layer (which may soon be on it's own physical tier).  Works well for me but is obviously a very simple scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a caching system for EntityFramework (with EDMX) http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32

Here is how you use that example with CodeFirst
http://jkowalski.com/2010/04/23/logging-sql-statements-in-entity-frameworkcode-first/

Although he is demoing the tracing provider rather than the caching provider you can use the same principals